# DDL and DML on EDW from SQL Server using LinkedServer does not work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I need to drop and recreate table and insert on EDW environment from SQL Server. From "PRINT @DropTable" below, I get the result:

```
 N'EXEC (''DROP TABLE dbname.tablename;'') AT [linkedserver];'
```

And if I run it manually:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC (''DROP TABLE dbname.tablename;'') AT [linkedserver];'
```

, it works.  But when I run

```
EXEC sp_executesql @DropTable
```

, it gives me the error:

> N'EXEC (''DROP TABLE dbname.tablename;'') AT [linkedserver];' Msg 102,
>   Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC ('DROP TABLE
>   dbname.tablename;') AT [linkedserver];'.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @TDQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @OpenQry NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableToDrop VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @DropTable NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DropTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @linkedServer VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @linkedDbName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TabExists BIT

DECLARE CUR_QRY CURSOR FOR
SELECT TableName, TDQuery FROM dbo.tbl_TABLE

OPEN CUR_QRY
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_QRY INTO @TableName, @TDQuery

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

SET  @linkedServer='linkedserver'
SET @linkedDbName='dbname'
SET @OpenQry='Select count(1) as TabExists FROM DBC.TABLES WHERE TABLEKIND=''T'' AND DATABASENAME=''dbname'' AND TABLENAME=''' +@TableName+ ''''
SET @OpenQry = N'select @TabExists = CASE WHEN TabExists = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END from OPENQUERY('+@linkedServer+', ''' + REPLACE(@OpenQry, '''', '''''') + ''')'
EXEC sp_executesql @OpenQry, N'@TabExists BIT OUT', @TabExists OUT;

PRINT @TabExists
IF @TabExists = 1 

PRINT @TableName
SET @DropTableSQL = N'''''DROP TABLE dbname.'+ @TableName+';''''';

PRINT @DropTableSQL

SELECT @DropTable = 'N'''+ N'EXEC (' + @DropTableSQL + N') AT [linkedserver];'''

PRINT @DropTable

EXEC sp_executesql @DropTable

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_QRY INTO @TableName, @TDQuery
END
CLOSE CUR_QRY
DEALLOCATE CUR_QRY
```

Comment: Remove first **`N`** from `SELECT @DropTable = 'N'''+ N'EXEC (' + @DropTableSQL + N') AT [linkedserver];'''`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I removed fist N and also remove two single quotes from @DropTableSQL so it works!

Comment: Great to hear it works. I post it as answer so you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `@DropTable` is itself of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` so there is no need for first **N** in:

```
SELECT @DropTable = 'N'''+ N'EXEC (' + @DropTableSQL + N') AT [linkedserver];'''
```

Remove it and it should work.